How would you say "argument" as in "Do those arguments sound compelling to you?"?

Please also note that argumentum does not mean "argument" and compellens does not mean "compelling" and possum is not an animal.
How would you ask "Do those arguments sound compelling to you?" in Latin?

So, what is a good Latin word for "argument"? Wiktionary claims that "argument" is the primary meaning of "argumentum". Now, Lewis&Short says that there is a difference between "argumentum" and "ratio", basically, that "argumentum" rests upon facts and that "ratio" rests upon reason, so that "argumentum" might be better translated as "evidence" rather than "argument":

and in particular, that which rests upon facts, while ratio is that which depends upon reasoning
https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=argumentum

Thomas Aquinas called his five arguments for the existence of God "quinque viae", so he used "via" to mean "argument".
An example of an "argument" that I was referring to was that, if the Illyrian language was a centum language, then "Curicum" (the ancient name for Krk, the northernmost island in the Adriatic sea) can be read as "northern wind" (from *(s)kjeh1weros). I gave five such "arguments" in my forum post and then I wrote "Audiunturne ea argumenta vobis compellentia?". I certainly wouldn't use "via" to describe my "argument", but I don't know whether I should use "argumentum" or "ratio". Or perhaps "evidentia"?

Do you want to go for a specific era of Latin? This feels like a question where classical and medieval solutions can look wildly different. Cicero made arguments in court, for example, so there must be a natural classical way to phrase this, too. I expect argumentum to be mainly a later choice, but only attestations will show which way it really is.

Disputatio means argument. So does altercatio if yelling is involved. An argumentum is a statement in support of a disputatio. Argumenta illa vim habent tibi?
